# Ruby on Rails:I am now making the function of creating a group on SNS, but stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb, rails-activerecord

I am in trouble because I can't get it why my code doesn't work.
I am now trying to show the names of the members who click the link"Join This Group" to join a group on the page(show.html.erb-group).

## 【Models】

Group: columns⇒id,name etc

Member:columns⇒id,name etc

GroupInMember:columns⇒group_id, member_id

## 【Controller】

## groups_controller.rb

```
def show
  @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @member =Member.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # show.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @group }
 end
end

def join
 if GroupInMember.where(:member_id => session[:login].id, :group_id =>params[:id]).exists?    
 then
   GroupInMember.where(:member_id => session[:login].id, :group_id =>
   params[:id]).each do |g|
     g.destroy
   end
 else
 GroupInMember.new({:member_id => session[:login].id, :group_id　　   
 =>params[:id].to_i}).save
 end
end
```

## show.html.erb-groups

```
<% @group.group_in_members.each do |m| %><p>
 <li><%= Member.find(m.member_id).name %></li><p>
<% end %><p>

<%= link_to 'Join this group', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'show', :id =>
 @group.id }%>|<p>
```

## 【How to solve this?】

I tried this codes but failed to show the names on the page through the click.
I checked "GroupInMember"model in rails console but no additional information was added after the click.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Which line of code calls join()?  How about:

```
<%= link_to 'Join this group', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'join', :id =>
 @group.id }%>|<p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. You are right. Now I understand it is necessary to jump to the page described as a method when I want "action".

Answer (score 0):

In the groups#show action, what does params[:id] refer to?
  I think, you should use different names to receive id os the group and id of the member.

```
@group = Group.find(params[:id])
@member = Member.find(params[:id])
```

is not going to work.
  You want to do something like

```
@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
@member = @group.members.find(params[:id])
```